# Using Typescript, how can I print to output window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have started to develop a web application using Typescript in Visual Studio. I'd like to know how can I print my values to output window in Visual Studio. `console.log(....)` prints to browser console; but what should I use to print in Visual Studio itself.

Comment: I don't think that is going to be possible.  It's running in the browser so how can VS know what is going on with console?

Comment: @CoreyAlix It might run in a NodeJS environment as well, and I wouldn't say it's impossible to redirect NodeJS output to the Visual Studio command line. I don't know how to do that, but it sounds perfectly reasonable and feasible to achieve.

Comment: Other than console.log(), is there any other command available to print in VS itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want what you can do is select Debug|Window | Javascript Console.[1] This also works for Typescript programs since they are converted to Javascript before being sent to the browser.

You can do this using Visual Studio Code which is much more suitable for Typescript and can output the console, using Chrome, to the window inside. It can also examine variables and the stack.

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688631.aspx

Comment: Looks like you missed a ":" after your [1] to put the hyperlink in the correct place.  Also, not sure why you are recommending a lesser version of Visual Studio since they are already using visual studio.

Comment: As far as Typescript is concerned it is not a lesser version and can use the  latest version of it. It is also faster to start up and build projects. There are no spurious dll's created as a hang over from C#. It also works well with Chrome for debugging in Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

For single file in Visual Studio.

> tsc filename.ts

compiles and converts to JS.

> node filename.js

it displayed output in VS `console/terminal`.